# MySql REGEXP search for anything with opening and closing square brackets

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I am trying to get from database anything that contains enclosed square brackets. My attempt was the following:

```
select count(*)
from table t
where t.string regexp '@\\[@\\]@'
group by t.TID
```

Examples of strings I am trying to get:

```
foo[foo]foo
foo[foo]
[foo]foo
[foo]
[]
```

Comment: What about `foo [ bar` and `][` and `]]]]]]` ?

Comment: And `[nested[brackets]etc]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the fastest:

```
LIKE '%[%]%' -- finds all of your test items plus some more.
```

If you need the brackets to be "balanced", that is a tougher problem, especially if they can be "nested".

`REGEXP` is more expressive than, but slower than, `LIKE`.  No apparent need for `REGEXP`.

Backslashes will be needed in a `REGEXP`, not not in a `LIKE`.

Comment: Thank you, no I fortunately am not dealing with nesting of brackets, not sure if it would be even possible with LIKE or REGEXP.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like):

```
where t.string LIKE '%[%' OR t.string LIKE '%]%'
```

In this case, you just do not need a REGEXP-based search.

Comment: Thanks a lot, btw why did some people write in some other questions that you need to put \\ in front of square brackets?

Comment: *Because MySQL uses the C escape syntax in strings (for example, “\n” to represent the newline character), you must double any “\” that you use in your REGEXP strings* (from [MySQL REGEXP documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)). I suggest using **LIKE** and it does not require escaping the square brackets because it cannot be treated as a regular epxression special character.

Comment: Note that this Answer will match `unbalanced [ bracket`, etc.

Comment: The number of backslashes needed depends on the number of languages you are going through to get to the desired parser.